# Gracefully handle an aborted HTTP authentication browser login attempt in Symfony 2 application

Tags: symfony, security, http-authentication, symfony-2.8

I would like to gracefully handle an aborted HTTP login attempt in my SF2 application.

Currently, when I click the following anchor I get the standard browser HTTP authentication pop-up. However, if I click 'cancel' I get through to a blank `/secret/landing`.

How can I modify my security/firewall configuration to simply close the modal and remain on the same page?

`<a href="/secret/landing/">Sign In</a>`

My `security.yml` looks like this:

```
security:
    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory:
                users:
                    crmpiccosecret:
                        password: rfc1872
                        roles: 'ROLE_SECRET'
    firewalls:
        secret:
            pattern: ^/secret/$
            anonymous: true
        secret_secured:
            pattern: ^/secret/.*$
            http_basic: ~
            provider: in_memory
            context: secret
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/secret, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/secret/.*, roles: ROLE_SECRET }
```

[image]

Comment: it's not connected to Symfony it's up to browser how to handle this. I think that default is to leave user on page requested by him but without rendering anything.

Comment: I'd say, before starting anything crazy, you'd be better of by implementing a simple [form login](https://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login_setup.html). It's quickly done, and you get access to a lot more configurability.

Comment: you may take a  a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726860/apache-authentication-redirect-on-failure-reliably

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the desired behaviour can be achieved by changing the href to `data-href`, or something arbitrary:

`<a data-href="/secret/landing/" class="btn btn--primary inline--block sign-in-button no--margin-b">Sign In</a>`

and then making the request via AJAX. So, if it aborted then we stay on the same page but if it's successful then you are taken to that page by means of a JavaScript redirect.

This example is in CoffeeScript, because that is what I am using but the code is quite minimal and can be converted to JavaScript/jQuery as needed:

```
  secretSignInButtonClickHandler: (e) =>
    e.preventDefault()

    href = $(e.currentTarget).attr('data-href')

    $.ajax
      url: href
      success: (response) =>
        document.location = href
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

You can deal with it on `.htaccess` level:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#if authorization header is empty (non-authenticated client)
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} !=""
RewriteRule ^$ /your/landing-page [L]
```

You need to have `mod_rewrite` enabled.

But i would strongly recommend to change your authentication system to simple login form - it will give you much more control on it.

Comment: Thanks, is there no way to configure this within the application (particularly inside the SF2 security settings)? As you can see from my screenshot it is Firefox that i'm using, however the same behaviour occurs on Chrome. It seems strange that the default behaviour is to continue navigating to the route and simply show a white screen/blank page. I will consider changing to a login form, but it is out of scope for the moment.

Comment: In case of http_basic - it's handled mostly outside of Symfony, you can't configure it from app. Default authentication for Symfony is login form.

Comment: OK, I will look into adding it to `.htaccess`. Does you example cover the entire application rather than just one specific page?

Comment: it covers whole page.

Comment: Sorry Pawel, I'm not with you. I wouldn't want to check for HTTP authorisation on every page request it would only be on /secret/* any other part of the site is publicly accessible.

Comment: So you should change your authentication to something else than http_basic.

Comment: Check out this page - https://www.httpwatch.com/httpgallery/authentication/ if you scroll down to "Example 10" and click the button that says "Display Image" that seems to handle cancelling/aborting the login dialog quite well. I'm trying to work out how they do that as that is _exactly_ the behaviour I am looking for.

Comment: But it's not connected at all to Symfony configuration - and you asked about that. You can play with it but on server configuration level.

Comment: Hmmm, I wonder if it's possible to grab the entered username and password and capture the submission of the HTTP login modal with jQuery/JavaScript and then check the HTTP response code and redirect if it is, otherwise close. It might not be possible, but that URL certainly does something similar although the source code looks quite minimal.