# How can I detect if user escapes out of Authentication Required dialog in browser?

Tags: javascript, html, browser

How can I detect if user escapes out of Authentication Required dialog in browser?

Is there JS for this cancel / escape key event ?

[image]

I don't need to know which user, just to redirect them to a unauthorized page.

Comment: you may hook a event handler to the cancel button.

Comment: I would be surprised if you could use javascript for this, as the Auth request is coming directly from the server and no html page is being rendered yet... I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726860/apache-authentication-redirect-on-failure-reliably but it is from 2010 and not sure if it is still valid.

Answer (score 2):

I honestly have no experience with this specific popup, but it is part of the [Basic Authentication protocol](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) inherent to HTTP. What happens is when the browser requests a protected resource from a web server, the server responds with an unauthorized status code (401) and a header called `WWW-Authenticate`, and the browser shows this popup on its own. This popup is not related to JavaScript in any way, and as such, we can't detect it using JS.

We can, however, check for the presence of the `Authorization` header in the client's response on the server, and if the header exists, and is correct, then serve the protected route; otherwise, serve a different route. I don't know if it's possible to check for the header on the page, since it's not loaded yet, but you can definitely have your server make that decision before serving the response.